# How to change CSS using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change the CSS using jQuery:

```js
$(init);
    
function init() {
    $("h1").css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
    $("#myParagraph").css({"backgroundColor":"black","color":"white");
    $(".bordered").css("border", "1px solid black");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bordered">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p id="myParagraph">This is some paragraph text</p>
</div>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: it's been fixed. As replied below, there are two solutions: (1) remove the curly brace and change backgroundColor to background-color (css class) or - the core problem) put the missing curly brase at the end and use the DOM/JS notation witch also works. THANKS EVERYONE!

Comment: manipulating CSS in javascript can be considered poor practice. Consider add/remove/toggling classes.

Answer (score 258):

Ignore the people that are suggesting that the property name is the issue.  The jQuery API documentation explicitly states that either notation is acceptable: http://api.jquery.com/css/

The actual problem is that you are missing a closing curly brace on this line:

```
$("#myParagraph").css({"backgroundColor":"black","color":"white");
```

Change it to this:

```
$("#myParagraph").css({"backgroundColor": "black", "color": "white"});
```

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YPYz8/

```js
$(init);
    
function init() {
    $("h1").css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
    $("#myParagraph").css({ "backgroundColor": "black", "color": "white" });
    $(".bordered").css("border", "1px solid black");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bordered">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p id="myParagraph">This is some paragraph text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you add a value as a variable, for example `paddingTop` as *x* number of px? Every kind of syntax I've tried has resulted in an error.

Comment: Never mind. Got it: `$("#main").css({paddingTop: (var_name+20) + "px"});`

Comment: @Ender: using `css()` all the css is reset and only the css mentioned in this function persists. How can I only add css which is to be changed and retain previous css ?

Answer (score 69):

You can do either:

```
$("h1").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Or:

```
$("h1").css({backgroundColor: "yellow"});
```

Comment: `{"backgroundColor": "yellow"}` is valid, though superfluous.

Comment: @user449914: you don't need to put quotes around the property names in an object literal - `{foo: "bar"}` is the same as `{"foo": "bar"}`.

Answer (score 25):

To clear things up a little, since some of the answers are providing incorrect information:

---

The jQuery **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** method allows the use of either DOM or CSS notation in many cases. So, both `backgroundColor` and `background-color` will get the job done.

Additionally, when you call `.css()` with arguments you have two choices as to what the arguments can be. They can either be 2 comma separated strings representing a css property and its value, or it can be a Javascript object containing one or more key value pairs of CSS properties and values.

In conclusion the only thing wrong with your code is a missing `}`. The line should read:

```
$("#myParagraph").css({"backgroundColor":"black","color":"white"});
```

You cannot leave the curly brackets out, but you may leave the quotes out from around `backgroundColor` and `color`. If you use `background-color` you must put quotes around it because of the hyphen.

In general, it's a good habit to quote your Javascript objects, **[since problems can arise if you do not quote an existing keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3710417/186636)**.

---

A final note is that about the jQuery **[.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)** method

```
$(handler);
```

is **synonymous** with:

```
$(document).ready(handler);
```

as well as with a third not recommended form.

This means that `$(init)` is completely correct, since `init` is the handler in that instance. So, `init` will be fired when the DOM is constructed.

Answer (score 11):

The `.css()` method makes it super simple to find and set CSS properties and combined with other methods like .animate(), you can make some cool effects on your site.

In its simplest form, the `.css()` method can set a single CSS property for a particular set of matched elements. You just pass the property and value as strings and the element’s CSS properties are changed.

`$('.example').css('background-color', 'red');`

This would set the ‘background-color’ property to ‘red’ for any element that had the class of ‘example’.

But you aren’t limited to just changing one property at a time. Sure, you could add a bunch of identical jQuery objects, each changing just one property at a time, but this is making several, unnecessary calls to the DOM and is a lot of repeated code.

Instead, you can pass the `.css()` method a Javascript object that contains the properties and values as key/value pairs. This way, each property will then be set on the jQuery object all at once.

```
$('.example').css({
    'background-color': 'red',
    'border' : '1px solid red',
    'color' : 'white',
    'font-size': '32px',
    'text-align' : 'center',
    'display' : 'inline-block'
});
```

This will change all of these CSS properties on the ‘.example’ elements.

Answer (score 10):

When you are using Multiple css property with jQuery then you must use the curly Brace in starting and in the end. You are missing the ending curly brace.

```
function init() {
 $("h1").css("backgroundColor", "yellow");

 $("#myParagraph").css({"background-color":"black","color":"white"});

 $(".bordered").css("border", "1px solid black");
}
```

You can have a look at this [jQuery CSS Selector tutorial](http://jstricks.com/jquery-css-methods-selectors/).

Answer (score 5):

```
 If you have one css:

   $("p").css("background-color": "pink");

If you have more than one css: 

  $("p").css({"background-color": "pink", "font-size": "200%"});

Or you can use:

var style ="background-color:red;";
$("p").attr("style", style);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add that when using numbers for values with the css method you have to add them outside the apostrophe and then add the CSS **unit** in apostrophes.

```
$('.block').css('width',50 + '%');
```

or

```
var $block = $('.block')    

$block.css({ 'width': 50 + '%', 'height': 4 + 'em', 'background': '#FFDAB9' });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
         $('h1').css('color','#3498db');
      });
    </script>
    <style>
      .wrapper{
        height:450px;
        background:#ededed;
        text-align:center
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

$(".radioValue").css({"background-color":"-webkit-linear-gradient(#e9e9e9,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.43137254901960786),#e9e9e9)","color":"#454545",    "padding": "8px"});

Comment: A little explanation should help too.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){ 
$('.bordered').css({
"border":"1px solid #EFEFEF",
"margin":"0 auto",
"width":"80%"
});

$('h1').css({
"margin-left":"10px"
});

$('#myParagraph').css({
"margin-left":"10px",
"font-family":"sans-serif"
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bordered">
<h1>Header</h1>
<p id="myParagraph">This is some paragraph text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

wrong code:`$("#myParagraph").css({"backgroundColor":"black","color":"white");`

its  missing   `"}"` after `white"`

change it to this

```
 $("#myParagraph").css({"background-color":"black","color":"white"});
```

Comment: You just repeated the most popular answer, only 3 1/2 years later.

Answer (score 0):

$('#recordsCount').text('Total Records: ' + filteredData.length).css({"background-color": "white", "border": "1px solid black"});

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).