# Distinguishing between two same HTML ID elements using Jquery and css in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I know that is a bad practice to have more than HTML elements having same ID. However such is my situation where I need to specifically modify either of them.

I [researched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498579/how-jquery-works-when-there-are-multiple-elements-with-the-same-id) around and found about [Jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/P2j3f/257/) method 'document.getElementByID' that returns with the first similar element and lets you change it using [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730035/how-to-change-css-using-jquery). Using that I wrote the code below but it doesn't work.

```
$(document.getElementById('it_trending-3')).css({"display":"none"});
```

I have added this code in my wordpress theme using the [CSS-JS-PHP wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js-php/), created a shortcut from the same and then added the shortcode. Can someone please guide me what and where I went wrong?

Also feel free to suggest a different function that would maybe let me specifically point to each of the same ID elements using maybe indexes. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just add a different class to each and refer to each by `$(".classname")` ( "." period is for classes "#" is for id's ) since it looks like you are using jQuery or `document.getElementByClassName` with javascript. You would never do `$(document.getElementById('it_trending-3'))` as it is combining JavaScript with jQuery in the wrong way.

Comment: You should really just use classes if you plan on using something more than once. Could you give some context as to why you HAVE to use the ID twice?

Comment: The classnames are same as well. It is basically a wordpress template and such is the design that a section in the site acting as a container for the widgets can only be placed once on the homepage meaning that i cannot have widgets anywhere else or at different places. And if you do copy the section again, it basically duplicates creating same id, same classes, same everything. Which is why Iam trying to differ the IDs and remove some widgets from the 1st section and remove the alternative ones in the second duplicate section thereby creating two seperate widget sections for me.

Answer (score 2):

Keep a class to the divs you want to change:

```
<div>
    <span id="a" class="test">1</span>
    <span id="b" class="test">2</span>
    <span>3</span>
</div>
```

The Jquery would go like this:

```
$(function() {
    var w = $("div");
    console.log($('#a').length);
    console.log($('body #a').length);
    console.log($('#a', w).length);
});

$(".test").first().css({"color":"orange"});
//or
$(".test:first").css({"color":"orange"});
```

But if you want to select any specific element with the class via an index of sorts, then you would need to do it like this:

```
var x = $(".test");
$(x[1]).css({"color":"orange"});
```

Comment: He said the ID's have to be the same even though it's bad practice.

Comment: Im actually trying to understand what situations that you can keep id's the same....

Comment: You can never use an ID more than once. ID's are to be unique, classes are for reusability and can be used as many times as required.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, Now if that is the case, he can keep a class and using jquery's `first()` he can select the first element in that class.

Comment: It's more efficient to do something like `$("#wrapper .classname:first")` as opposed to using the jQuery `first` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Venkat! However it is only working for the first element. Is there a way I can point to seperate IDs specifically using index numbers or something?
Here's what I have till now:



`(function($) {
$(".widget.clearfix.Trending:last").css("display", "none");
})(jQuery);`

Comment: I tried using the `:nth-child()` selector as well and this the logic code. `$(".widget.clearfix.Trending:nth-child(2)").css("display", "none");` but still only the first elements goes display:none not the second as it should

Comment: No instead of `nth-child`, You would need to do something like this: `var x = $(".widget.clearfix.Trending"); $(x[2]).css("display":"none");`

Comment: unfortunately it is not working for me and none of the elements go display:none. Here is the complete code iam executing: `(function($) {
var x = $(".widget.clearfix.Trending"); 
$(x[2]).css("display":"none");
}) (jQuery);`

Comment: Its `$(x[2]).css({"display":"none"});` not `$(x[2]).css("display":"none");`

Comment: Iam afraid it is still not working. Resulta are back to square one with no elements going display:none. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Logically speaking, the solution should work, if its not, there must be a problem somewhere else....

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in 2 ways.

Based on element's hierarchy or based on class attribute / custom data attribute to the element.

In the below example we have 3 span elements with the same id and we have to apply 3 colors to each of those span elements.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <span id="it_trending-3">
    Applying css to same Id with hierarchy  (span in 1st div)
  </span>
</div>
<div>
<span id="it_trending-3">
Applying css to same Id with hierarchy (span in 2nd div)
</span>
</div>

<br /><br /><br />
<span id="it_trending-3" class="testcls">
  Applying css to same Id with class
</span>
```

1. Applying css using js / jquery based on element hierarchy

**JQuery**

```
(function($){
  $("div:last #it_trending-3").css("color", "red");
  $("div:first #it_trending-3").css("color", "green");
})(jQuery);
```

2. Based on class attribute / custom data attribute to the element.

**JQuery**

```
(function($){
  $("#it_trending-3.testcls").css("color", "blue");
})(jQuery);
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9q30rjnq/)