# How to set background-color and border using javascript

Tags: javascript, border, background-color

I have a script that needs background-color and border filled.  CSS should do the trick but a piece of code where I should add the property is javascript. Here's that piece of code... (Sorry guys, I'm not much of a javascript guy.  Thanks in advance!!!)

```
        $(this).find('.slide-tabs li').eq(showIndex).css({
            opacity: 1
            >>>background-color: #fff<<<
            >>>border: 2px solid #ddd<<<
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change CSS using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730035/how-to-change-css-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

you need to enclosed `key` in double quote if json key contains special chars like `-(in background-color)` . Otherwise json is wrong. & Javascript throw error.
&  also if value is string like #fff must enclosed in quote `"#fff"` in js.

```
$(this).find('.slide-tabs li').eq(showIndex).css({
    "opacity": 1,
    "background-color": "#fff",
    "border": "2px solid #ddd"
});
```

Comment: You can also use camelCase syntaxe if you have special chars in keys : `.css({ opacity : 1, backgroundColor : "#fff", border : "2px solid #ddd" }).

Comment: @JoelHecht Actually, it's not suppose to be in css. I am suppose to write the background-color: #fff and border: 2px solid #ddd inside the javascript file, and not inside <script> code.

Comment: @Kaushal The way I wrote the codes above is just a thought.  I need the correct syntax using javascript.

Comment: @Dave Moreno. All answers here are javascript, not css. The ".css" function is part of jquery, the javascript lib that you are also using in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using that code directly in a `<script>` then you need to use `document` not `this`. And also you can make use of `addClass` to add a custom class to the HTML element. Using `addClass` makes the code manageable and easy to read and modify when you need effect on numbers of CSS properties.

```js
var showIndex = 0;
$(document).find('.slide-tabs li').eq(showIndex).addClass('li-custom');
```

```css
.li-custom{
    opacity: 1;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<ul class='slide-tabs'>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>  

</body>
```

Comment: Your answer works but in a different sense. You see, you declare the showIndex=0. Hence, the li-custom stays at the first child of <li>.  The <li> is from a slider. And I need it to be in-sync with the current or active slide. Thanks for your answer though. Unless you need to help me more...?

Comment: I will be happy to help you further. So you say you want `li-custom` in the `<li>` that has `active` class in it?

Comment: The <li> tags are script generated. It doesn't have a class="active" in it. Just plain <li>.  Any class will do as long as it will keep on syncing with the current slide.

Comment: Does your `<li>` always append at the end of `<ul>` into which you require `li-custom` class?

Comment: li-custom or "active" is required to... an active slide. the jquery that I've acquired did not put a current or active class when an active slide is displayed.  That's why I'm struggling to put or insert an active class using javascript. If not possible, or i'd be given a choice, I'd rather choose to put or declare the background and border...(see script above)

Answer (score 0):

In my dillema to either insert a custom class or modified property using javascript, I've come up with a solution.  Instead of bothering to do all those, I decided to do it using css.  In my problem, the javascript or jquery that I've used doesn't produced an active class, so there was no way to modify them using css ().  Until I've found out that I can modify it after all with css by reconstructing the rule: li[style*="opacity: 1"]{}.  So all of the list that starts with that, will proceed to your desired modification.